# Why does this C sizeof function show different values in different contexts?

Tags: c, sizeof

Some context: iOS app development. Objective-C code in Xcode.

This one has been confounding me for hours:

I have a little struct I created:

```
struct EIVertex {
    GLKVector3      P;
    GLKVector3      N;
    GLKVector3      barycentric;
    GLKVector2      st;
};
```

`GLKVector3` and `GLKVector2` are types found in the GLKit framework.

Here is what is weird:

```
sizeof(GLKVector2) = 8
sizeof(GLKVector3) = 12
sizeof(EIVertex) = 48
```

The size for `EIVertex` is **48** but should be **44** (12 + 12 + 12 + 8 = 44).

Can someone please explain why there is this size disparity?

Comment: There might be padding in the memory layout. The padding is used to get the member's address correctly aligned to some boundaries. In this case most likely 32-bit boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Structures in C tend to be padded for data alignment. Check [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Typical_alignment_of_C_structs_on_x86) for more information. Also refer to the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing).